# How to do Stateful Bootstrap 4 Tab Navigation in Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, tabs, ruby-on-rails-6

Currently I have a Rails 6 app using Bootstrap 4's tab component. The tab component works slick! However, I find it to be a terrible user experience when refreshing or navigating forward then back resets the tab to the default tab. I'm going to say that keeping it in the URL (instead of cookies or localstorage) is a requirement because the need to share links. See image - upon page load the details tab is open, then I click on contacts tab, refresh then reverts back to the details tab. Goal is on that refresh to keep the contacts tab open.

[image]

Question 1) How can one keep the state of the tab in the URL? Best practices, things to consider, etc.

Question 2) Perhaps my desired approach is wrong from the start. What would be good alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so:

In your view do something like:

```
<%
  tabs = %w(Details Contacts Projects Orders Batches)
  selected_tab = params[:tab] || tabs.first
%>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <% tabs.each do |tab| %>
    <%= render 'shared/tab', tab: tab, active: selected_tab == tab %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

then a partial shared/_tab.html.erb

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <%= link_to title, company_path(@company, selected_tab: tab),
                     class: "nav-link#{ active ? ' active' : '' }" %>
</li>
```

Comment: This does a page refresh, then. Is there pretty much no other way? One could use Javascript to modify the location history I suppose and directly modify the URL without a page refresh?

Comment: I've tried using the tabs javascript plugin and editing the history with pushState but couldn't get it to work reliably.  Turbolinks and the above gives a reliable and speedy experience.